# Common result from two queries

Tags: sql, excel

I'm working on two SQL queries. Query 1 pulls data where employee spent more than 8 hours a day in office, so it looks like:

```
select a.empname, a.empid 
from emp a 
join shift b on a.dept=b.dept
where empid is not null
and a.month= '1'
group by a.empname, a.empid 
having count (shifthours)>8

intersect

select a.empname, a.empid 
from emp a 
join shift b on `a.dept` = `b.dept`
where empid is not null
and a.month='2'
group by `a.empname, a.empid` 
having count (`shifthours`)>9
```

When I run this query, it does not pull the correct result. If I run both queries separately and use VLOOKUP in Excel, it gives me the correct result.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  There are numerous reasons why your query would not produce results consistent with the your description.

Comment: Does `shift` contain individual employee data?  It doesn't make sense to me that you are only joining on department.

Comment: Do you have the single quotes in the actual second query?  It looks odd to surround  two columns ith quotes (`'a.empname, a.empid'`)